# Get returned array values from object into variable PHP

Tags: php, xml, database, arrays, object

I'm quite new to OOP PHP and I've wrote a class to get Lat/Long from Google's map API. This is kinda irrelevant as that works fine.

From the class I return an array of the LAT/LONG/ADDRESS values as seen below:

```
    class latLngFinder {

    /**
    * Creates cURL connection to Google API v3
    * @param string $url The URL to read from
    * @return string The URL content
    */
    private function getURL($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $tmp = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($tmp != false){
            return $tmp;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Get Latitude/Longitude/Formatted Address based on an address
    * @param string $address The address for finding coordinates
    * @return array An array containing Latitude/Longitude/Formatted Address
    */
    public function findCoord($address){
        $address = str_replace(' ', '+', $address);
        $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=' . $address . '&sensor=false';
        $data = $this->getURL($url);
        if ($data){
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
            $status = $xml->status;

            // Use this to debug returned XML
            //print_r($xml);

            if ($status == 'OK'){
                // Find Latitude/Longitude/Formatted Address in XML
                $lat = array( (string) $xml->result->geometry->location->lat);
                $lng = array( (string) $xml->result->geometry->location->lng);
                $formatted_addr = array( (string) $xml->result->formatted_address);

            }
        }
        // Return data
        return array('formatted_address' =>  $formatted_addr[0], 'lat' => $lat[0], 'lng' => $lng[0]);

    }


};
```

When I create the class object:

```
 // Include class
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/class.latLngFinder.php');

    // Initialise the latLngFinder class
    $obj = new latLngFinder();

    print_r($obj->findCoord($row['address']));
```

I want to get the array that was returned from the class, this is where I am stuck. I've tried using:

```
$var = print_r($obj->findCoord($row['address']), true);
```

However this returns the array as a string which I do not want. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: have u tried like $var = $obj->findCoord($row['address']); print_r($var, true); ?

Comment: yes, that still returns a string not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
class latLngFinder {
    public $output;
    public $lat;
    public $lng;
    public $formatted_address;

    public function __construct($inputaddress)
    {
        $this->address = $inputaddress;
        $this->output = $this->findCoord();
    }

    /**
    * Creates cURL connection to Google API v3
    * @param string $url The URL to read from
    * @return string The URL content
    */
    private function getURL($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $tmp = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($tmp != false){
            return $tmp;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Get Latitude/Longitude/Formatted Address based on an address
    * @param string $address The address for finding coordinates
    * @return array An array containing Latitude/Longitude/Formatted Address
    */
    private function findCoord(){
        $address = str_replace(' ', '+', $this->address);
        $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=' . $address . '&sensor=false';
        $data = $this->getURL($url);
        if ($data){
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
            $status = $xml->status;

            // Use this to debug returned XML
            //print_r($xml);

            if ($status == 'OK'){
                // Find Latitude/Longitude/Formatted Address in XML
                $lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
                $lng = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
                $formatted_addr = $xml->result->formatted_address;
                $this->lat = $lat;
                $this->lng = $lng;
                $this->formatted_address = $formatted_addr;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Initialise the latLngFinder class
$obj = new latLngFinder($row['address']);
echo $obj->lat;
echo "<br />";
echo $obj->lng;
echo "<br />";
echo $obj->formatted_address;
?>
```

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined property: latLngFinder::$lat I guess the $lat variable needs to be declared? I don't really know how to do that

Comment: hold on I forgot to return the vars 2 mins

Comment: ok I don't get the error now but nothing is returned on screen.

Comment: sorry i was calling an incorrect function (copy and pasted from some of my code) try again slightly updated now

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot re-assign $this in line 60
(private function findCoord($this->$address){)

Comment: fixed it now sorry not quite fully awake yet.

Comment: Great it works now! however I'm still getting a few errors:

PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for latLngFinder::__construct(), called in test.php on line 25 and defined in class.latLngFinder.php on line 33
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: inputaddress in class.latLngFinder.php on line 35

Comment: just put `public $inputaddress` at the top that should solve it I think.

Comment: I fixed it using:

    public function __construct($input_address = '')

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: That works too.  There's probably a better way of structuring the class tbh but I'm just not doing too well today :)